# How to handle errors with Cloudinary Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

As per cloudinary JS API, an upload call looks like:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudinary

cloudinary.uploader.upload(fileLocation, function(result) {
   ..something
 });
```

There is no error returned in the callback. How do I capture the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `v2` version of the SDK, e.g.,:

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload("sample.jpg", 
    function(error, result) {console.log(result); });
```

Here's a reference:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/blob/master/test/uploader_spec.coffee#L233-L236

Answer (score 0):

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(image, function(result) { 
  if (result.error) {
     //error
  }
}
```